# Material UI - Difference between using Icon component and Material Icons node module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add Material Icons to my app. However, Material UI has provided two ways to add the same icon to my website:

1. [`<Icon />` component](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#icon-font-icons), which is included in the `@material-ui/core` package:

   ```html
   <!-- Add this in <head> section of index.html -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
   ```

   ```
   import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';  // Import <Icon />

   function Star() {
     return <Icon>star</Icon>;
   }
   ```
2. Installing the [`@material-ui/icons` package](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#material-icons), then import the corresponding icon:

   ```
   $ npm install @material-ui/icons
   ```

   ```
   import StarIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Star';  // Import from node module

   function Star() {
     return <StarIcon />;
   }
   ```

Therefore, I want to ask is there any differences in terms of **performance** (ie. loading time) or **bundle size** for the above two methods if I wish to add Material Icons (not other font icons) to my webpage? Thanks a lot!

Comment: CDNs are usually faster than locals so the first one should be better in performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few differences:

1. CDN is faster and more preferable for users of your application because the same files will be received in a cached form from a nearby server rather than your server. Not a big difference nowadays.
2. Main reason why i believe people do still install packages is because it's easier to work with your package in IDEs.

If you aren't planning on using Material-UI a lot i'd say don't bother installing the entire package through npm and just use CDN link.